# Bipartite Graph (undirected)

Tags: colors, graph

I am taking an input, e.g.
4
1 3
1 2
2 4

First line is number of nodes, lines after that are the edges.  I have to attempt to color the graph, and if I can't, I need to list a cycle in the graph that is causing the error.

This is fine so far, except one of the graphs contains 1,000,000 nodes.  Everytime I try to use it I get a Stack Overflow error, even though I streamlined it more, and raised the max heap size of eclipse to 1024m.

I'm not asking for code, just asking if I am doing something blatantly wrong to keep getting errors.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: First and foremost, you could try specifying a language -- I'm assuming Java? -- and perhaps some details of how you're presently going about it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: nice agreement ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could optimize your cycle detection algorithm. 
This might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Other than that, a million nodes plus adjacency matrix might as well be too much to handle at once, so perhaps there's a way to just load parts of the graph at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bipartite graph you can always colour it with only two colours (e.g. colour the first partition white, and the second partition black).

Usually when one thinks of colouring a graph he should specify the number of colours. You can always colour a graph by assigning to each node a different colour. Another example: for planar graphs only four colour are required. However, for most graphs the [chromatic number] of a graph is [NP].

[NP] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems

[chromatic number] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

Answer (score -1):

Well, this *IS* an NP complete problem (longest cycle), so this sort of thing IS likely to happen.

I'd probably just bump the heap again, and let it run...

EDIT: Never mind. got my reduction backwards.

Comment: -1. It may be that determining the *longest* cycle is NP-complete, but we're only interested in determining if there are any odd-length cycles, which most certainly is not: for each connected component of the graph, choose a vertex and colour it red, then recurse on all of its children, colouring them blue, then recurse on their children, colouring them red again, etc. Ignore children already coloured. If the algo terminates without ever trying to recolour a red node as blue or vice versa, the graph is bipartite, otherwise it's non-bipartite. O(|E|) time.